# Installed Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office Second Edition - Add Visio Panel to Toolbox

Tags: winforms, vsto, visio

I have installed Visual Studio 2005 for Office Second Edition.

I wish to embed a Visio diagram into my WinForms C# application. However, I don't have any new items in the toolbox.

I have searched Google but cannot resolve the issue myself.

Comment: have you tried to update toolbox manualy from dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTO is for a different thing (it's for creating Visio addins), it is, well, unrelated to what you are after.

There are two Visio controls you can use in your C# application: Visio Viewer control (allows you to view Visio drawing in a C# application), and Visio Drawing control (allows you to modify a Visio drawing in your C# application). To get them, you must have either Visio or Visio Viewer installed.

To get them in your toolbox:

1. Right click the toolbox -> Choose items..
2. In the "Choose toolbox items" dialog, select tab "COM components"
3. Select either "Microsoft Visio Drawing control" (drawing control) or "Visio Document" (viewer), click OK
4. Now you should get your control in the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

VSTO doesn't provide anything for that.

What you are looking for is called OLE, Object Linking and Embedding. Originally released in 1990, Microsoft Office was the last main Microsoft product that still supported it. Time has not been kind to OLE, the protocol was complicated and very hard to get right. Also very detrimental to program stability, you would not just import another program's windows and UI but all of its bugs as well.

Notable is that the .NET framework shipped without any support for it at all. Office 2007 was the last one that supported it but there were several nasty and unsolvable problems with it. DsoFramer was removed from the Microsoft servers just before Office 2010 beta was released.

This is gone forever and won't come back. Move forward by embedding your UI into the Office program, not the other way around. Very well supported in VS with its Office project templates. There are 3rd party products that support embedding a word processor or spreadsheet in your own program.

See [How do i embed MS word to a windows form app?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4572e41b-8dce-476b-ab49-69bbc405bc9a/how-do-i-embed-ms-word-to-a-windows-form-app?forum=csharpgeneral) for more information.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Visio.

Comment: Visio is a part of the Microsoft Office suite.

Comment: Yep, but still it's always been kind of "stand aside", ever since it became MS product - so there are some things that apply to the office, which, however, do not apply to the Visio